# Custom taxonomy hide meta box but show in menu

Tags: custom-taxonomy, metabox, taxonomy

If set `show_ui` `false`, this hide the taxonomy meta box and admin menu link both, how to hide only meta box?

```
$args = array(
    'hierarchical'      => true,
    'labels'            => $labels,
    'show_ui'           => false,
    'show_admin_column' => false,
    'show_in_menu'      => true,
    'show_in_nav_menus' => true,
    'query_var'         => true,
    'rewrite'           => array( 'slug' => 'wheel' ),
);

register_taxonomy( 'wheel', array( 'product' ), $args );
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're looking for the `meta_box_cb` argument.

```
$args = array(
    'hierarchical'      => true,
    'labels'            => $labels,
    'show_ui'           => false,
    'show_admin_column' => false,
    'show_in_menu'      => true,
    'show_in_nav_menus' => true,
    'query_var'         => true,
    'rewrite'           => array( 'slug' => 'wheel' ),

    'meta_box_cb'       => false,
);

register_taxonomy( 'wheel', array( 'product' ), $args );
```

You can also define a custom callback function for displaying your own metabox if you'd like. Refer to the [documentation for register_taxonomy()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_taxonomy/).

Answer (score 0):

i registered the taxonomy without showing any of the UI element

```
add_action( 'init', 'kia_register_featured_tax', 0 );

function kia_register_featured_tax(){
    if(!taxonomy_exists('portfolio_featured')){
        $labels = array(
            'name' => _x( 'Featured', $this->plugin_domain ),
            'singular_name' => _x( 'Featured', $this->plugin_domain )           
        );

        $args = array(
            'labels' => $labels,
            'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'portfolio-featured' ),
            'query_var' => true,
            'public' => true,
            'show_ui' => false,
            'show_tagcloud' => false,
            'show_in_nav_menus' => false,
        );
        register_taxonomy( 'portfolio_featured', array( 'portfolio' ), $args );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To clarify the answer from @NateWr, you need to set `show_ui` to `true`, set `show_in_menu` to `true` and set `meta_box_cb` to `false`:

```
$args = array(
    'show_ui'           => true,
    'show_in_menu'      => true,
    'meta_box_cb'       => false,
    //Plus anything else you need...
);

register_taxonomy( 'wheel', array( 'product' ), $args );
```